# Adding an OPTIONAL clause to a SPARQL query using Jena ARQ

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, jena

Is it possible to programmatically add an OPTIONAL clause to a SPARQL query using the Jena ARQ API?
I would like to programmatically take this query:

```
select ?concept ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o . } limit 10
```

To this:

```
SELECT  ?concept ?p ?o ?test WHERE
{ 
 ?s ?p ?o
 OPTIONAL { ?concept <http://www.test.com/test> ?test }
}
LIMIT   10
```

Through ARQ it's simple to add the additional result variable `?test`:

```java
Query q = QueryFactory.create(query)    
query.addResultVar(var);
```

But from what I've found in the API docs and trawling across the net it's not possible to add an OPTIONAL clause. Do I need to use a different library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. See [this introduction to the topic](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/manipulating_sparql_using_arq.html) on the apache jena site.

Your starting point is getting the [query pattern](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/Query.html#getQueryPattern%28%29):

```
Element pattern = q.getQueryPattern();
```

That will be an `ElementGroup` if I remember correctly. Add the optional in there:

```
((ElementGroup) pattern).addElement(new ElementOptional(...));
```

The `...` bit will be an [ElementTriplesBlock](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/syntax/ElementTriplesBlock.html), which is pretty straightforward.

Inelegant, however. In general I'd recommend using visitors and the algebra representation, but this direct route should work.