# adding a filter clause to jena to a SPARQL query using Jena ARQ

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I have a jena query say `select * where {?S ?p ? O}` and I want to add a limit at the end to be `select * where {?S ?p ? O} LIMIT 100`, the approach proposed in [Adding an OPTIONAL clause to a SPARQL query using Jena ARQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594304/adding-an-optional-clause-to-a-sparql-query-using-jena-arq)  doesn’t work because there is no ElementLimit type of class and I also don't want to do string manipulation because there might be existing LIMIT clause which in that case I want to change the bound of existing clause.

Comment: If you have a Query object, could you use [setLimit(long)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Query.html#setLimit-long-) ?

Answer (score 2):

`Element*` are syntax items for things in the pattern matching.  Limit is part fo the query level, not the pattern matching.

Asked on the jena users list [the question was about `OpLimit`](http://jena%20users%20list%20the%20question%20was%20about%20%60OpLimit%60). Use `OpSlice` which is offset+limit combined.